# Rails Active Storage in Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rails-activestorage

I'm running a docker compose which consists of a web worker, a postgres database and a redis sidekiq worker. I created a background job to process images after uploading user images. ActiveStorage is used to store images. Normally without docker, in local development, the images are stored in a temporary storage folder to simulate a cloud storage. I'm fairly new to Docker, so I'm not sure how storage works. I believe storage in Docker works a bit differently. The sidekiq worker seems fine, it just seems like it's complaining about not able to find a place to store images. Below is the error that I get from the sidekiq worker.

`WARN: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /myapp/storage`

And here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  setup:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - RAILS_ENV=development
    command: "bin/rails db:migrate"
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecurepass
      - POSTGRES_DB=myapp_development
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data
  postgres_data:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data
    command: /bin/true
  sidekiq:
    build: .
    environment:
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379
    depends_on:
      - redis
    command: "bin/bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml"
  redis:
    image: redis:4-alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  web:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
      - setup
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    environment:
      - REDIS_URL=redis://localhost:6379
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

Comment: Can you share your `Dockerfile` too.

Comment: @thatway_3 here you go

`FROM ruby:2.4.1-alpine

RUN apk --update add nodejs netcat-openbsd postgresql-dev imagemagick
RUN apk --update add --virtual build-dependencies make g++

RUN mkdir /myapp

WORKDIR /myapp

ADD Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock

RUN bundle install
RUN apk del build-dependencies && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

ADD . /kirim

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]`

Comment: Can you try yo add `RUN chown -R root:root /myapp` before `ENTRYPOINT ` command.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to add `myapp` volume for `sidekiq` as well like this:

```
  sidekiq:
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this comment! 


I had an issue running some containers in CircleCI, where I cannot use volumes, and basically, the thing was failing because I always use it locally with volumes and it works, but when I removed the volumes for the CI environment, the 2 containers (rails and sidekiq) were not sharing the same disk, so ActiveStorage was breaking! 

After one day of debugging, this comment made me realize how dumb I was for not seeing that :)



Thanks!